# scala error: bad symbolic reference

Tags: scala, sbt, play-json

I was using sbt to compile a scala code, and got the following error message

```
[error] /user/xyin/Projects/measurement_wspark/src/main/scala/json2csv.scala:41: bad symbolic reference. A signature in DefaultReads.class refers to term time
[error] in package java which is not available.
[error] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
[error] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling DefaultReads.class.
[error]         val ts = (json \ "RequestTimestamp").validate[String]
[error]                                                      ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

I was using the play json library to parse json files in my main class. And the content of the build.sbt file is like the following:

```
name := "json_parser"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1"
resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.4.8"
```

I am totally new to scala and the play framework. Does anyone has any clue about this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what does this have to do with Spark. It's a scala compilation error probably related to play-json.

Comment: What is your Java version? (Is there a special reason you are not using Scala 2.11(.8)?)

Comment: @Gábor Bakos The java version is 1.7.0_85. Our hadoop cluster only has scala 2.10 installed.

Comment: @xyin It seems Play JSON 2.4.8 (or one/some of its dependencies) was compiled for Java 8, so it most probably will not work on Java7. You can try to recompile with Java 7 or use a version that was compiled with Java 6 or Java 7.